# using loop or temporary table, which one gives better performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am just beginner in SQL Server. I have few concern over the performance variance between using a loop or temporary table. And is there any simple way to do

```
(x+y ) + (x+y ) + (x+y ) /  sum(x)
```

in a single query.

this is what i have did

```
select cast(datetime as date) as date,DATEPART(hour,datetime) as hour,sum(product)  as         Total 
from temp_aggregated_speed 
group by cast(datetime as date), DATEPART(hour,datetime)
 order by cast(datetime as date),DATEPART(hour,datetime);
```

will store this in a variable and process (one more query there to find sum of x ). Is there any way to do it in a single query?

Comment: At least try something before giving up and asking someone else to think for you. If this is going to be the way you approach SQL SERVER or any programming for that matter its going to be a hard road for you ahead.

Comment: Try it. Meassure the difference, read the execution plans. ask questions about what you have seen.

Comment: The only way to really know how different options will perform is to try it with *your* tables, with *your* data, *your* hardware, etc. There's no generic "always do X" advice - if there was, and there was always a simple way to map between alternatives X and Y, then the product would already have been changed to automatically rewrite Y as X behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your equation with some basic algebra will often improve performance while also making your designs less complex. Your example equation can be rewritten as follows:

```
  ( (x+y) + (x+y) + (x+y)...) / sum(x)
= ( sum(x+y) ) / sum(x)
= ( sum(x) + sum(y) ) / sum(x)
= sum(x)/sum(x) + sum(y)/sum(x)
= 1 + sum(y)/sum(x)
```

If X and Y are in the same table, the SQL query is this simple:

```
select blah, 1 + sum(y)/sum(x) as FinalAnswer
from thetable
group by blah
```

Be sure your datatypes are compatible, you may have to do some typecasting to get the mathematical part to behave the way you want. For example:

```
select blah, cast(1.0 as float) + sum(cast(y as float))/sum(cast(x as float)) as FinalAnswer
from thetable
group by blah
```